# How to concatenate parameter in query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use a parameter in the following query, but I am not really sure how to.

`$id` will be 1, 2 or 3 etc. and I want to select where C.Name is Galleri1, or Galleri2 etc.

This is what I got so far, but I am not sure how to add $id.

```
function getGallery($id){

$data = array();

 $Q = $this->db->query('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
           FROM products AS P
           LEFT JOIN categories C
           ON C.id = P.category_id
           WHERE C.Name = "Galleri($id)"
           AND p.status = "active"
           ');
```

UPDATE: I am using PHP and MySQL

Comment: Do you want to search by the ID or the name? Since you don't have the name value in your function you can only search by the ID passed into the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is:

```
function getGallery($id){

$data = array();

 $Q = $this->db->query('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
                   FROM products AS P
                   LEFT JOIN categories C
                   ON C.id = P.category_id
                   WHERE C.Name = "Gallery' . $id . '"
                   AND p.status = "active"
                   ');
```

Note: I fixed the spelling of Gallery in the query, as I think it was probably a typo:

```
Galleri
```

to:

```
Gallery
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: To prevent SQL injection use instead:

```
function getGallery($id){

$data = array();

$id = str_replace("'", "''",  $id);

$query = 'SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
                   FROM products AS P
                   LEFT JOIN categories C
                   ON C.id = P.category_id
                   WHERE C.Name = "Gallery' . $id . '"
                   AND p.status = "active"
                   '
 $Q = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: This may have possible SQL injection attack. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: True, but this isn't a question about SQL Security, it's a question about how to add the parameter to the string. I'll edit my answer accordingly though.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

First you create a string for gallery name. "Galleri1", "Galleri2" etc. Then bind that string as parameter to query.

Something like this:

```
  $sth = $this->prepare('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
               FROM products AS P
               LEFT JOIN categories C
               ON C.id = P.category_id
               WHERE C.Name = ?
               AND p.status = "active"
               ');

 $gallery_name = "Galleri$id";
 $sth->bind_param( 1, $gallery_name );

 $q = $sth->execute();
```

Constructing a query string from parameter like others answerers have suggested may open door for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you are not careful. For example, what happens if `$id="' OR 1=1 OR C.Name !='"` and you concatenate it to query string?

Using parameter binding, like I have showed above, prevents this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use PHP. Probably something like

```
function getGallery($id){

    $data = array();

    $Q = $this->db->query("SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName
                      FROM products AS P
                      LEFT JOIN categories C
                      ON C.id = P.category_id
                      WHERE C.Name = 'Galleri$id'
                      AND p.status = 'active'
                      ");
```

You should however be aware of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injections) as well, so escape it first (if it isn't done in some other place):

```
function getGallery($id) {
    $id = $this->db->escape($db); // or similar
```

If your database class support [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements#Parameterized_statements), you should use them instead.